# Copy and paste within same table with ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have created a new attribute in a shapefile in order to copy the same information existing in the attribute ObjectID.

Is it possible to copy and paste information from one attribute to another within the same table using ModelBuilder?

If not, is there any way using ModelBuilder, to copy information from an existing attribute to a new attribute within the same table?

Answer (score 2):

Try **calculate field** tool with expression !column_name!

Where column_name is the column from which you want to get value